# How to proccess/read java objects from xmlrpc received by a server

Tags: java, python, dictionary, hashmap

First, im learning java, so i am totally new with it, i am making a petition to a python function with xmlrpc, python sents a dictionary which contanins another dictionary inside, and various ids lists like this:

```
{
    country_ids=[1,2,3,4,6,7,8],
    state_ids=[23,22,12,12,56,12,56,72,23],
    config={GLOBAL_DC=true, MAX_GLOBAL_DC=1,RET=5,COMP=1,VER=1.0}
}
```

So im getting this in java with:

```
HashMap<String, Object> data=HashMap<String, Object> xmlrpc.call...
```

and i am getting something like this:

```
{
    country_ids=[Ljava.lang.Object;@7e0aa6f, 
    state_ids=[Ljava.lang.Object;@dc6c405,
    config={GLOBAL_DC=true, MAX_GLOBAL_DC=1,RET=5,COMP=1,VER=1.0}
    }
```

I know how to read value from the hashmap with **data.get("country_ids")** but, i don't know how to map/read/convert this object to get the ids inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone cames here wondering the same or similar question, i found how has to be done:

```
Object [] country_ids = (Object[]) data.get('country_ids');
// To read the data of elements, something like this
for (Integer i = 0; i < country_ids.length; i++) {
    Log.d("Element value of " + i.toString(),country_ids[i].toString());
}
```